# accessing multiple web pages at a time using c#

Tags: c#

my project need to read multiple web pages at a time(eg: for a particular keyword google will display 100 pages result maximum)  I tried to read that 100 pages using 'for' loop in URL.But it is showing http request exception in c#.How can i read that pages within sort period of time???

Comment: Please post the code that you already have, this would make helping you a lot easier.

Comment: 2 questions, not one. First - how to do it faste rthan in a for loop. Second - help you actually not make a mistake with your request, so that you dont get an exception.

Comment: You seem to have adopted the moniker of another - there is already a well know Nikhil K. Maybe you could be respectful to him and change yours to something slightly different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is really nice

http://blogs.msdn.com/somasegar/archive/2009/11/18/reactive-extensions-for-net-rx.aspx 
http://www.minddriven.de/?p=550

But maybe you can not use RX .

Answer (score 1):

To do it in parallel, push the code onto the ThreadPool. It will not run 100 threads at once (but you don't want that).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you either try to access a disposed object or you don't dispose it, thus leaving too much connections open.

Post some code for more help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution. But doing so many requests in parallel is **very** bad, so you have to do some mechanism to reduce number off simultaneous threads.

```
void QueueWorkItems()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        new Action<string>(Request).BeginInvoke("http://www.google.com/search?q=test&start=" + (i * 10), null, null);
}

void Request(string url)
{
    //Process your request
}
```

Comment: no,i mean each results have links(urls) to other websites. All that links i need to access.